# События браузера на мобильных устройствах

Tags: gwt, javascript, java

Есть приложение, написанное на GWT. Если открывать его на планшете (Android, iPad), некоторые события не приходят. Узнал, что есть специальные события для таких устройств. 
Вопрос: как определить, какие мне события нужно использовать `OnTouchStart / OnTouchMove / OnTouchEnd / OnTouchCancel` или обычные JS-события?

Comment: @Trash, Какая версия GWT? Как я понял, выше 2.3?

Comment: Да, 2.4 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TouchEvent.isSupported()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/TouchEvent.html#isSupported())